# Change session variable value fails

Tags: python, session, flask

**EDIT: actually, I can see the value of the session variable changed, but in the next call to the function the value is set back to 0**

I am a Flask beginner and I have problems in changing the value of a session variable. Here is an excerpt of my code:
**EDIT after first round of comments**

0) I set the `SECRET_KEY` variable in my config.py.

1) when a user logs in I set a session variable:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    session['info_released'] = 0
    app.logger.debug('info_released session value: {}'.format(session['info_released'])
    ...
```

Checking the log, the value of the session variable is correctly set to 0.

2) I have a `counter` variable passed via `request.json` that is incremented from time to time. Between one `counter` increment and the following one I check the following condition several times (via an ajax call):

```
@app.route('/get_actual_demand', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_actual_demand():

    app.logger.info('> SESSION: {}'.format(session['info_released']))
    if request.json['counter'] == 10 and session['info_released'] == 0:
        #code
        session['info_released'] = 1
        app.logger.info('> SESSION VAR. AFTER CHANGE: {}'.format(session['info_released']))
        return jsonify(released=1)
    else:
        return jsonify(released=0)
```

That is, when `counter == 10` I check the condition many times but I want to run the `#code` only once (the first time the `counter == 10` and the session variable is 0).

**EDIT:** Checking the log, the `session['info_released']` is changed to 1 when `counter == 10`, but in the next call the value is set back to 0: indeed, the `#code` is run many times until the `counter` gets incremented.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I may also have the program flow better organized, but I don't think it matters with the problem I am having.

**EDIT:** it seems that everything I do on the session variables inside the `get_actual_demand()` view function are only "local". I changed the code as follows, removing the `session['info_released'] = 0` from the `login()` function:

```
@app.route('/get_actual_demand', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_actual_demand():
    # the variable session['info_released'] is no more
    # defined in the login() function

    if request.json['counter'] == 10:
        try:
            # The first time I get here, raise a KeyError exception
            if session['info_released'] == 1:
                return jsonify(released=0)
        except KeyError:
            # Use `session['info_released']` as a flag,
            # defined here
            session['info_released'] = 1
            return jsonify(released=1)
    else:
        return jsonify(released=0)
```

Checking the log (removed from the code) I can see the session variable defined when it first hits the exception, but then hits again the exception as if the session variable is still not present.

I think there is something missing in my configuration, but I can't find hints in the documentation. My config.py is as follows:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'oqEr[]*woi+145@#11!&$fsa%(Mn21eq'
    SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ='postgresql+psycopg2://libra:password@localhost/mydb'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your counter is 10, and where do you store your counter variable. Is this also a session variable, or you are using some kind of external cache?

Comment: could you try adding line `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` just after `if` statement? that will open a debugger in console where your local server is running. There you can check all variable's values

Comment: Where is the second snippet of code located at? I think you need to show how these two snippets are related. Are they in the same view function or different?

Comment: @Miguel: the two snippets are in different view functions

Comment: @Boris: The `counter` is not a session variable: it is actually passed to the function containing the `if` condition (second snippet) and is taken from the database. There is another function that periodically increment the variable on the database.

Comment: I have edited the question providing an extended second snippet.

Comment: @Libra Thanks for clarifying! I don't see anything wrong with the snippets you posted. How many python processes are you running, and is your session shared between processes? Are you calling login route by accident? Also, do you have any other code that would reset your session variable?

Comment: @Boris: Uhm. I am not sure I get your question right: I think I am running one process, the flask app is served by gunicorn, so I don't think it's a problem of shared variables. The session var is set to 0 only in the login function, and I don't call in again after the user is logged.

Comment: I have added another snippet, it seems that everything I do on session variable inside the function is only "local". Please, help, I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it using Flask-Session extension which adds support for Server-side Session to your application.
Here is the URL:

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/

I added the next lines to my app:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)
```

and that's all. No need secret keys.

Hope this helps.